# Why tinymce looks ugly if I put it inside <div class="row"></div>?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, tinymce

I have a problem with  TinyMCE, it looks like in the picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFBlp.png)

my HTML is:

```html
<form action="#" method="post" id="create-product">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <label for="#product-name">Product name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <input type="text" name="product-name" class="form-control"                         id="product-name" placeholder="Product name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <label for="#product-category">Product category</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <select name="product-category" class="selectpicker form-control" id="product-category" required>
                        <option value="null">--none--</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <label for="#product-description">Product description</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <textarea name="product-description" id="product-description"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success create-product-btn w-25 m-auto"><i class="far fa-save"></i>Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

But if I remove  tag, it will fix the issue whitout knowing the reason.
I'm Using Tinymce 4.7.13 and bootstrap 4,
Thanks.

Comment: Can not reproduce the issue. All seems to work fine.

Comment: I found the reason, it's because of custom css    .col-4 ,.col-8{display:flex; align-item:center}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was this style who caused the problem:

```css
 .col-4 ,.col-8{
 display:flex; 
 align-item:center
 }
```